# changing the value of a label in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Why isn't this working ? I've tried, `document.getElementById('Mname').value= memberName;`, which didn't work.

```
function memberVP () {
    var use r= getConnectedUserFromStorage();
    var memberName =user.name;
    alert( memberName );
    document.getElementById('Mname').InnerHTML = memberName;
}
```

Comment: `innerHTML` not `InnerHTML`.

Comment: also you have a space between use and r --> var use r , this might have been a typo when you copy pasted your code...

Answer (score 1):

The correct name of the attribute is `innerHTML` and not `InnerHTML`. Correcting this, you will get that you want.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you got your mistake that is `InnerHTML` should be `innerHTML`. Also one more clarification that is a `value` attribute is used only for `inputs`.

A `label` do not have a `value`.